# Workbook.VbaProject throws NullReference exception

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel spreadsheet with VbaProject macros and I'm running some simple code to do the calculations:

```
var workBook = package.Workbook;
workBook.CalcMode = ExcelCalcMode.Automatic;
workBook.FullCalcOnLoad = true;

SetExcelInputs(specifications, workBook);

workBook.Calculate(options);
```

This worked perfectly fine until the vendor sent a new version of the spreadsheet. As far as I can tell, both are identical and contain the same VbaProject in the macros section. But the latest one will not load the macros: [new](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuwu5.png) vs [original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92elT.png)

All permissions are identical in both sheets.
Thoughts?

I compared both the old and the new spreadsheets side by side, checked permissions, checked if macros are enabled. Everything seems to be in order, except the second one won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating EPPlus to the latest version solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a Tools - References type of difference. Worth a try.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this?

Comment: You go to Tools - References in both macros in both files, and see if they have the same references selected. Maybe your error comes from lack of reference.

Comment: I checked the reference and they are the same for both files, so this didn't solve it, unfortunately.